# Country/Region and City List in a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, sql

I need to create a dropdownlist with the Region (Asia, South East Asia, North America,..etc) and the Country together in the same dropdownlist.
Upon selecting the options, then i will populate the City based on the Country selected.

It will look something like this, but in a dropdownlist instead of expanding it out. 
With Singapore, Australia, Cambodia,etc as Region in my case, and the Cities shown, as Country.
[image]

Or more specifically, like the following , with Taiwan, Mainland China as Region, and the Cities as Country for my case.:

[image]

All my data are pulled from my database, with my RegionTable that looks like this

[image]

and my CountryTable like this :

[image]

I've got the code working fine for populating the cities based on Country selected, the problem now is that i do not know how to put the region into the same dropdown with the Country. The only problem is how do i add in the Region and making it not selectable because, users should be selecting the Country instead of the Region.

Im using the following code to get my CountryDropDownList

```
function loadPackage_CountryList() {
$('#Package_Country option').each(function (i, option) { $(option).remove(); });
$('#Package_Country').attr('disabled', true);
$("#Package_Country").append("<option value=''>Downloading...</option>");
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", url: PackageWSURL + "/GetPackageCountryList", data: "",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var countries = response.d;
        $('#Package_Country option').each(function (i, option) { $(option).remove(); });
        $('#Package_Country').attr('disabled', false);
        for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
            $("#Package_Country").append("<option value='" + countries[i].Value + "'>" + countries[i].Display + "</option>");
        }
    }
});
```

}

Anybody can help me on how to add Region into the Dropdownlist?
Thanks in advance.

--------------Edited----------------------

This is my WebMethod of getting the data from my database.

```
 [WebMethod]
public List<jsonItem> GetPackageCountryList()
{
    List<jsonItem> RecordList = new List<jsonItem>();

    jsonItem jItemA = new jsonItem();
    jItemA.Display = "All Countries";
    jItemA.Value = "ALL";
    jItemA.Group = "---";
    RecordList.Add(jItemA);

    String ConnStr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TOUR_DB_ConStr"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnStr);
    connection.Open();

    try
    {
        String SQL = "SELECT [CountryList].[CountryCode], [CountryList].[CountryName], [CountryList].[Regioncode] ";
        SQL += "FROM [CountryTable] ";
        SQL += "WHERE [CountryTable].[Activation] = 1 ";
        SQL += "ORDER BY [CountryTable].[Regioncode], [CountryTable].[CountryName]";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, connection);
        SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            jsonItem RecordItem = new jsonItem();

            RecordItem.Display = dataReader["CountryName"].ToString() + " - " + dataReader["CountryCode"].ToString();
            RecordItem.Value = dataReader["CountryCode"].ToString();
            RecordItem.Group = getRegionName(dataReader["RegionCode"].ToString());
            RecordList.Add(RecordItem);
        }
        dataReader.Close();
    }
    catch { }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }

    return RecordList;
}
```

I've managed to add in the optgroup from the function below, but the problem now is that i think it will auto add in the `<optgroup>` at the end of the line even though i've add in the `if` `else` function.

```
function loadPackage_CountryList() {
$('#Package_Country option').each(function (i, option) { $(option).remove(); });
$('#Package_Country').attr('disabled', true);
$("#Package_Country").append("<option value=''>Downloading...</option>");
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", url: PackageWSURL + "/GetPackageCountryList", data: "",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var countries = response.d;
        var group = "";
        $('#Package_Country option').each(function (i, option) { $(option).remove(); });
        $('#Package_Country').attr('disabled', false);
        for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
            group = countries[i].Group;
            if (group != "---") {
                $("#Package_Country").append("<optgroup label='" + countries[i].Group + "'><option value='" + countries[i].Value + "'>" + countries[i].Display + "</option>");
                if (group != countries[i].Group)
                { $("#Package_Country").append("</optgroup>"); }
                else { continue; }

            }
            else { $("#Package_Country").append("<option value='" + countries[i].Value + "'>" + countries[i].Display + "</option>"); }


        }
    }
});
```

}

so now it looks like this instead

[image]

notice how Asia got repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use [optgroup](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp) feature of select. If you can point the tech you use (WebForms, MVC) I can further help

**Edit**

I would change your **for** with this code

```
var selectCountries = $("select#Package_Country");
for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    group = countries[i].Group;
    var optgroupRegion = null;
    if (group !== "---") {
        optgroupRegion = selectCountries.find("optgroup[label='" + group + "']");
        if (optgroupRegion.length === 0) {
            optgroupRegion = $("<optgroup></optgroup>").attr("label", group).appendTo(selectCountries);
        }
    }

    $("<option></option>").val(countries[i].Value).text(countries[i].Display).appendTo(optgroupRegion !==     null ? optgroupRegion : selectCountries);
}
```

The updated code would reuse an already added optgroup.

Comment: please look at me edited post. Im not sure how to add in the RegionCode now. Thank u in advance